# How to give computer account access to EMC VNX CIFS share?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, network-share, storage-area-network, cifs

I have a web application that runs using the `NETWORK SERVICE` account and which has a Virtual Directory to a shared folder (containing images) on an **EMC VNX NAS/SAN Unified Storage** file server.

I don't know much about those file servers that's why I am asking here on serverfault.

When I configure the web application to access the shared folder using my domain account, the application can load the images, however when I set the application use the `NETWORK SERVICE` account, (which would translate to the web server's `DOMAIN\MACHINE$` account), I am unable to access the files. Of course I have added the `DOMAIN\MACHINE$` account to the shared folder permissions as well as the NTFS permissions. I've even tested accessing shared folders on other Windows Servers using the `NETWORK SERVICE` account and they work.. I am unable to connect only to the EMC file server in this way.

I also ran *Process Monitor* on the web server and I see that the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` user gets a **0xC0000199** Result when trying to access the \fileserver\sharedfolder path.

I googled that status result and I get things like:

STATUS_NOLOGON_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT
"The account
used is a Computer Account. Use your global user account or local user
account to access this server."
and other results that seem to suggest that the problem is that I am using a computer account not a user account.

Also the Event Viewer from the file server, shows these two Failure Audits in the "Security" tab:

> Event ID: 681
>   The logon to account: MACHINE$
>   by: EMC NTLMSPP
>   from workstation: MACHINE
>   failed. The error code was: CIFS error: DC AUTH ERROR
>
> Event ID: 533
>   Logon Failure:
>   Reason: User not allowed to logon at this computer
>   User Name: MACHINE$
>   Domain: DOMAIN
>   Logon Type: 3
>   Logon Process: CIFS error: DC AUTH ERROR
>   Authentication Package: EMC NTLMSSP
>   Workstation Name: MACHINE

I do not know what configurations I need to put in place to allow computer accounts and I am assuming a lot of you server professionals have faced this issue before so if anyone can help me out I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure the service to run as an actual service account, and assign the correct NTFS permissions to that account on the fileshare.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by configuring the "service to run as an actual service account"? Could you please elaborate more on that? Which service are you referring to and how does one go about that? Thanks